# Is there a way to bind 2 java libraries with same namespace, same function names but different functionalities

Tags: xamarin.android, java-binding

I am creating an android App to read BLE devices of specific manufacturer. I have 2 jar libraries for 2 different BLE devices, but since the manufacturer is same for both the devices, I don't know why, but they have kept the namespace same for both the libraries. Over and above the name of the functions are same but they behave differently. 
So the problem is when I use both the libraries together, either in same android java binding project or different, they clashes. 
Is there any way to force the libraries to get accessed through different namespaces?

Comment: You can change the namespace using metadata. (in binding jar/aar step)

Comment: OK. I will check and let you know whether this approach works or not.

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue?

Comment: I haven't yet tried the @MehdiDehghani's suggestion but read some documentation in this respect and seems to me that can be done. I will be working on it in the next week. Meanwhile, go through the following documentation (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/) for getting any ideas